# Need to allow user to only select dates in a certain range in my view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, datepicker, data-annotations

I have a DateTime that we are using HTML5 to display the datepicker, and in certain instances, the user can only be allowed to select a date in a specific range.

This range is dynamic, and is based on another property.

In my model I have this property that is the date that is first displayed in the date picker:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
```

And I need the DateTime.MinValue of this property to be another property within the same object:

```
DateTime TruckPriorityDropOffFromMin { get; set; }
```

Range is not set up for datetime, so I know I would have to create a custom method for this so that it would check value of `TruckPriorityDropOffFromMin` and assign it to the min value.

I just don't know how to go about doing this, or if there is a better way of doing this without using jquery datepicker. We just need the user to only be able to select dates that are after the value of `TruckPriorityDropOffFromMin` property.

Comment: You better let the user selecting any date from the datepicker, and validate it on the submit button whether he selected it within your range or not, and then show the appropriate alert message!

Comment: Are you setting `min` and `max` attributes on your date input?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validate on server side then you can create a custom attribute class and then use it to validate your object -

```
public class ValidateMinDateAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
  private String Property { get; set; }

  public ValidateMinDateAttribute(String property)
  {
    Property = property;
  }

  protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext context)
  {
    Object instance = context.ObjectInstance;
    Type type = instance.GetType();
    Object propertyValue = type.GetProperty(Property).GetValue(instance, null);
    if (propertyValue < value or something else)//perform your check based on the value of the property, do conversion if you need
    {
      ValidationResult result = base.IsValid(value, context);
      return result;
    }
    return ValidationResult.Success;
  }
}
```

Then use it like this -

```
[ValidateMinDate("TruckPriorityDropOffFromMin")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
```

But if you want to test it on the client side then you need `javascripts` to test, like `jQuery`, or other `js` libraries.

NOTE: I don't have a visual studio here now, so cannot give a complete code, but this process should work.